# CountDowntimer exceeds the maximum duration in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, countdowntimer

I was making a simple fitness app which holds countdowntimer. but the problem is that  countdowntimer shows negative values.

it happens when it gets paused.

```
      progressBarExercise.progress = (workOutTimerDuration?.toInt() ?: 30) - exerciseProgress
```

Here is the problem, exerciseProgress becomes greater than workOutTimerDuration. so it gets negative values. I don't know how it's happening.

Comment: I recommend never using `@SuppressLint("SuspiciousIndentation")`. The warning exists for a reason. I've seen people coming on here with problems they spent hours on and they had that suppression on, and if they hadn't, their problem would have been found immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with how you're *"resuming"* your timer after you unpause. Calling `exerciseTimer.start()` **restarts it** with the same duration and tick parameters you used to create it. [From the source code](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java;drc=18de9f0156ef3c5956431230070cd42fcb340436;l=101):

```
// constructor stores the duration and tick length
public CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {
    mMillisInFuture = millisInFuture;
    mCountdownInterval = countDownInterval;
}

// onStart uses those lengths to restart the whole thing, starting from -now-
public synchronized final CountDownTimer start() {
    mCancelled = false;
    ...
    // this is when it ends, i.e. when onFinish() gets called. now + duration
    mStopTimeInFuture = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + mMillisInFuture;
    ...
}
```

So even though you're saving and restoring `workOutTimerDuration` and `exerciseProgress` when you pause and unpause, **you're not maintaining the state of the timer itself**. You're effectively restarting it from the beginning, with the full duration.

And this is a problem, because you're using the timer to update `exerciseProgress` on every tick. The timer doesn't stop when `exerciseProgress` reaches `workOutTimerDuration`, it stops when the timer runs for its full length.

That's fine when you start the timer with `exerciseProgress` at zero - but when you unpause, you're restoring whatever `exerciseProgress` was when you paused it. Now you're starting the timer with `exerciseProgress > 0`, so it's going to end up larger than `workOutTimerDuration` and give you a negative value when you subtract it.

---

So you have two approaches really. One is to make the timer `cancel()` itself once `exerciseProgress` hits a limit, so *that value* is what causes `onFinish` to get called, not the duration of the timer. That way you're not relying on the length of the timer at all, just the tick behaviour. The downside is that you lose accuracy - if you pause halfway through a tick, another tick will immediately fire when you unpause, so it kinda skips ahead in that sense.

The other approach is to store the state of the timer itself, so you can create one whose duration is the remaining time. You *could* do this by creating a new `CountdownTimer` with the remaining time as the duration - this runs into the same situation with the early tick though (which may or may not be a problem, maybe that kind of precision doesn't matter here!). Otherwise you'll have to create your own timer (e.g. posting `Runnables`, using a looping coroutine, etc.) which will give you more control over initialising it and controlling when the ticks happen. You could also use this kind of logic:

```
class MyTimer(val durationMillis: Long, val tickLength: Long = 1000L) {
    
    val timerEnd = System.currentTimeMillis() + durationMillis

    val remainingMillis
        get() = (timerEnd - System.currentTimeMillis()).coerceAtLeast(0L)
    val nextTick
        get() = remainingMillis % tickLength
    val ticksRemaining
        get() = remainingMillis / tickLength
}
```

which gives you the ability to hit the next tick at the right time (schedule an update `nextTick` millis in the future) even if you restart partway through one, and you can also see how many ticks are remaining and use that to calculate your progress, instead of having to maintain a separate value which could potentially go out of sync (like your `exerciseProgress` is doing). This way, everything's derived from the `durationMillis` value, and that's the only state you have to store.

Comment: thanks for your time and valuable information. I did use the first approach and it worked. I am using that approach for the time being. But will change it to last approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To make this happen, save the time during the timer's pause, and then add the difference between that time and the current system time to the `exerciseProgress` when the timer is started again.

```kotlin
private var isPause: Boolean = false
private var pauseTime: Long? = null // new property to store pause time
```

Add the following line inside the `if()` block of onPause()

```kotlin
pauseTime = System.currentTimeMillis() // save time of pause
```

And replace the onRestart() method as follows:

```kotlin
override fun onRestart() {
    super.onRestart()
    if (isPause) {
        restTimer?.start()
        exerciseTimer?.start()
        pauseTime?.let { pauseTime ->
            exerciseProgress += ((System.currentTimeMillis() - pauseTime) / 1000).toInt()    // add elapsed time during pause to exerciseProgress
    }
}
```